# Programming with .net

Tags: c#, .net

I've just recently learned C# and am interested in .net but I don't know where to begin.

I know .net is just a bunch of libraries and can be used for web programming?

I'm not quite sure what areas in .net that I need to learn? 
I don't know what I am trying to accomplish with .net? But I want to learn .net.

What other things can be achieved with .net?

Thanks.

Added -
The 2D class that I finished was a C#/Winform/XNA class working with 2d objects. Though there was never once a reference about .net in class. I just learned C# which is comparable to C++ and Java and Winform = just using the tool box and hooking up controls to back end code. XNA portion was being able to use the hardware to draw primitives and manipulate data going through the model->view->project pipeline.

What part of this class was .net? None right?

Comment: What are you going to develop? Websites, games, financial applications, ERP systems, widgets, 3d-graphic editors?

Comment: .NET is more than a bunch of libraries. It is a platform.

Comment: This reminded me of this for some reason: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FL7yD-0pqZg

Comment: Intriguing that you have 'learnt' C# without any knowledge of .NET... Anyway, .NET is your oyster. Let us know what you want to make, and wee can direct you what bits of the framework to learn/look into.

Comment: By "platform, not library" - the key point here is that you can't use a .NET program without a suitable CLI implementation (there are various available) - just like you can't run a java app without the JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know .net is just a bunch of libraries and can be used for web programming?

.NET is much more than this. It is not restricted to web programming. There are possibilities for doing Windows Applications (WPF), Web Applications (ASP.NET), Network Communication (WCF), Database Access (ADO.NET), ..., you name it. So just pick a language you would like to learn like C# and go ahead and visit [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/net/).

Answer (score 3):

You can do nearly anything with .net (the same is true for most other platforms).

You can use *ASP.NET* for web programming, *Windows Forms* or *Windows Presentation Foundation* for GUI development.

There are also lots of functionality for networking, database development and XML or Image processing.

But the question is, what do **you** want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

.Net is a managed runtime with libraries. It is not exclusive to building "web" applciation or pages.

- The .Net Framework is 'the libraries'.
- The CLR is the runtime (where the specification thereof, is deposited into a standarization organization)
- C#/VB.Net/F# are flavors of different syntaxus (how do you spell this in plural?) used to instruct the runtime, using the libraries, to perform actions in an order you define (AKA programming)

Wanting to learn .Net is akin to learning another language/gammar. If you have no previous knowledge of "language/gammar" itself, you are using this specific language/runtime to learn 'language' in general.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but if you've just used the toolbox to hook some stuff together you haven't learned C# or programming. You've learned how to hook some stuff together, but you're obviously interested in learning how it works. Seems like you're going to have to learn a lot of stuff from scratch. There's a lot to learn...

I think your best bet to learn .Net and C# (you can't really learn one without the other) apart from following a course specific for that goal is to **find yourself a good book** that explains the whole picture and run through the examples in the book.

Looking on internet, asking questions, and collecting bits of examples, etc. will give you little pieces of understanding, but I doubt you'll be able to get a comprehensive understanding of programming, .Net and C# that way, simply because you won't find a big picture explanation. I find a good book gives me a deeper understanding even though I've already worked with .Net/C# since it first came out, simply because there is much more explanation of **how** things work and **why**.

Personally I really like the Pro series from Apress: have a look at [Pro C# 2010 and the .Net 4 Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491)

It might be perfect or not depending on your understanding of software development. Otherwise just search for C# and see if other interesting books pop up.